# CentOS7 Yum Update, Conflict with Base and Update Repositories

Tags: centos, yum

I hadn't run into one like this before. Had a failed yum update when trying to update a server this morning. Package that is failing is dracut-network. I went ahead and updated the rest of the packages by skipping these, but still trying to figure this one out.

Basically, dracut-network is having conflicts between 2 repositories. But the repositories are the Base and the @updates.

I went ahead and ran both **yum distro-sync** and **yum clean all**

When I run yum update, I still get a ton of errors relating to dracut-network conflicting packages.

When I run:

```
yum list | grep dracut-network
```

I get:

```
dracut-network.x86_64                    033-360.el7_2.1                @updates
dracut-network.x86_64                    033-463.el7                    base
```

The actual errors are all related to this conflict. There's about a dozen conflicts but all look like:

```
file /usr/lib/dracut/modules.d/95iscsi/parse-iscsiroot.sh from install of dracut-network-033-463.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package dracut-network-033-360.el7_2.1.x86_64
```

Unless I'm missing something obvious here, how do I correct conflicting versions when they're both vendor repo's?